# Using Gephi 0.9.1 cant find NoverlapLayout plugin

Tags: gephi

Hi people in order to go beyond the basic functionalities of the software, I need to work with three additional plugins: GeoLayout, NoverlapLayout and Multimode Networks Transformation. I cant find any of those plugins. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I am surprised that you can't, I have all three installed in my Gephi 0.9.1 but it's been a while since I installed them so I don't know if they are currently unavailable for some reason. At least Noverlap comes bundled with Gephi, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not find any plugins you want in the Gephi, you can download from :https://gephi.org/plugins/#/
Open Gephi, Tools,Plugins:
[Plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE26F.png)

Click "Add plugins" and select the file you just downloaded.

Then you should have the plugins installed now.

Answer (score 0):

If people ever pass by, I had the same problem and in fact the name of the plugin has changed to only "Noverlap".

Here is the link to the plugin: https://gephi.org/plugins/#/plugin/noverlap.
You're welcome :)